# Tridion Publishing using code (PublisherFramework)

Tags: tridion

I'm trying to publish a page during Workflow. There are two environment that we are publishing to during workflow process: one to *test* and one to *live*. During the first automatic activity we are publishing to *test* and during that process the Components on the Pages don't need to be approved. We got that to work.

However when we approve the Page and the Page is being published to *live*, we need to make sure that we only publish approved Components (i.e. major versions).

In my code I'm using the Page.Publish method, but with that I can't specify that it should only publish approved items.

The publish method accepts an argument called `activateWorkflow`. When set to `True` it publishes both approved and unapproved items; but when set to `False` it gets added to the queue and we get a success message, but nothing gets published.

Anyone have any ideas how I can fix this, using the publishing method and without manually checking?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sharan - Welcome to SO - Please consider committing to our Area51 proposal to get a dedicated Q&A site for SDL Tridion at http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=eo63snjNlUWNn9xqeeO2NA2 - Your support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "PublisherFramework"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear where you are performing the activities, are you doing this from within your workflow activities in Visio?

Publishing will always only publish items that are either in the approved status for that target and items that have finished workflow (major versions).

All that said, I believethe reason you are getting empty PublishTransacctions is because you are calling the Publish() method on new items before you finish the page workflow activity (which means your new item is still in workflow, so the false value means there is nothing to publish which is not in workflow). Try calling FinishActivity() before the Publish() method is called.

Perhaps you could post your code from the final step so we can see exactly what you are doing.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by setting activateWorkflow=true when publishing to TEST and setting it to false when item has been approved. One thing that I had to do want to finish activity and approve before publishing to Live. Thanks for you suggestion!

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. Perhaps could accept the answer to help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into a similar issue when going through Component Workflow and having to publish static pages (no dynamic component presentations).

When publishing to test, as you mentioned, simply do activateWorkflow=true.  For your Live environment you need to kick off publishing after workflow completes.  I've resolved the issue via the event system for this.  Here an article that discusses this in more detail that may help you:

http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/autopublishing-on-workflow-finish

Comment: Thanks Nickoli, your suggestion worked great!! I was under the impression that setting the status to Content Approved would take the item out of workflow however it looks like I had to finish activity. Thanks Again!